# calcular la renta media

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo que calcular la renta media de los alumnos de un grupo que le pase.

Tengo que tener en cuenta 2 errores si no existe el grupo 20001 y si no existe alumnos 2002 hay alumno que su renta el nula.

No estoy seguro de si esto esta bien:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION RENTAMEDIA
    (v_alumnos_cod ALUMNOS.GRUPO%type) RETURN NUMBER  is
    v_rentaMedia number :=0;
    v_existe number;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_existe FROM grupos WHERE codgru= v_alumnos_cod;
    if v_existe=0 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'grupo inexisrtente');
    end if;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_existe FROM alumnos WHERE grupo= v_alumnos_cod;
    if v_existe=0 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'el grupo no tiene alumnos');
    end if;
    select avg(nvl(renta_fam,0)) into v_rentaMedia from alumnos where grupo= v_alumnos_cod;
    return v_rentaMedia;
End;
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu duda? ¿Qué no te funciona?

Comment: doble priemro no se priobarlo y segundo no se sie sta bien si tiene sentido

Comment: Yo no haría un `nvl` para convertir en cero los datos con valor `null`, pues eso me altera el promedio. Recordar que `null` significa **valor desconocido**. Si tengo 7 alumnos, conozco la renta de 5 y desconozco la de 2, para mi, el promedio debiera ser solo de los 5 conocidos. Si pongo en cero los otros dos, voy a bajar sustancialmente la media, en base a una suposición incorrecta.

Comment: y eso como lo hago? y como pruebo si funciona la funcion ?

Comment: invoca la función, declaras una variable, luego haces `var := RENTAMEDIA(1);` y puedes imprimir luego el valor de `var`.

Comment: eso que tieen que ver con lo que hablamos de los valores nulo no lo entiendo